# how to remotely bind to a webapi using kendo viewmodel

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a KendoUI grid for which I'm binding data retrieved from a WebAPI
I'm trying to bind the result to a kendo grid.

```
<div class="grid"></div>
```

The underlying .js code for Kendo is as shown below

```
/*
    */
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        transport: {
    read: {
        url: 'http://199.63.72.194/FusionAPI/api/Site/GetSiteDetails?siteId=64909fee-e52e-4051-8277-8ba2101e743b',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: "GET",
    }
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        sitename: {
                            type: "string"
                        },
                        address: {
                            type: "string"
                        },
                        contact: {
                            type: "string"
                        },
                        status: {
                            type: "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                data: "siteMaster",
            }
        }),
    });

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: viewModel.dtSource,
        height: 250,
        columns: [
            {
                field: "sitename",
                title: "Site Name"
            }, {
                field: "address",
                title: "Address"
            }, {
                field: "contact",
                title: "Contact"
            }, {
                field: "status",
                title: "Status"
            }
        ],
        pageable: true,
        sortable:true
});
```

However I get the response from Postman, but I'm not able to bind it to the grid

Where am I going wrong and what is that I'm missing

Comment: your url http://199.63.72.194/FusionAPI/api/Site/GetSiteDetails?siteId=64909fee-e52e-4051-8277-8ba2101e743b is not returning anything

Comment: I never see this before: Using `kendo.observable` as a DataSource. Can't you show any docs reference on this ? I'm pretty sure that if you change to `viewModel = new kendo.data.DataSource({.. ` and in the grid `dataSource: viewModel,`, it should work.

Comment: @JohnCena365 : That's an internal link. It wont return anything for you. You can replace it with any link which returns json data.

Comment: you cant use kendo observable, totally agree with @DontVoteMeDown

Answer (score 0):

You syntax for the datasource is not correct.

[Here is a link to the kendo documentation for a remote datasource using MVVM.](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mvvm/remote-binding)

[Here is a link to a grid example.](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/mvvm)

Basically, your syntax should be:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    products: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {....
```

Additionally, your grid needs to specify the data bind attributes.  For example:

```
<div data-role="grid"
  data-editable="true"
  data-toolbar="['create', 'save']"
  data-columns="[
             { 'field': 'ProductName', 'width': 270 },
             { 'field': 'UnitPrice' },
          ]"
  data-bind="source: products,
        visible: isVisible,
        events: {
          save: onSave
        }"
  style="height: 200px"></div>
```